# How define object that will be send to the other side?

Tags: wcf

How to define an object that will be send to the client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DataContract and the DataMember

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 SomePropertis
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```